# Entity Framework hangs when running first time

Tags: edmx

On running my application when i try to retrieve data through entityframework, it is taking more time, But it is normal next time. How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It does not hangs, actually the first query in EF is a cold query, which takes time. You can use Compiled query. and there are many ways you can improve performance.

Just go through below link, it will help you understand this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx